# matlab get the value of char

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

from MATLAB command line , when I type my variable a , it gives me values as expected :

```
a =


            value_1
            value_2
```

and I would like to access to each value of  a, I tried a(1) but this gives me empty 
the type of a is 1x49char.
how could I get value_1 and value_2 ?

```
 whos('a')
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  a         1x49               98  char
```

I get the a from xml file :

```
<flag ="value">
    <flow>toto</flow>
     <flow>titi</flow>
 </flag>
```

a+0:

```
ans =    
    10  32  32   32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  32  98,...
   111 111 108  101  97 110  95  84  10  32  32  32  32  32,...
   32   32  32   32  32  32  32  66  79  79  76  10  32  32,...
   32   32  32   32  32  32  32
```

Comment: You say the type of a is `1x49 char` That does not correspond to the commandline return you also specify.. Can you include the output of `whos('a')` to your question ^^

Comment: from workspace , the variable a has as value : <1x49char> and I would like to access to a(1) and a(2)

Comment: so that would be the first and second character in that string... This still is contradictory to saying that you get `value_1  value_2` when typing `a`+enter. I repeat: Can you include the output of `whos('a')` to your question. In the case `a` really is `1x49 char`, your question doesn't make any sense...

Comment: I added the results of whos('a) in my question

Comment: There you go, updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have an somewhat inconvenient character array. You can convert this array in a more manageable form by doing something like what @Richante said:

```
strings = strread(a, '%s', 'delimiter', sprintf('\n'));
```

Then you can reference to `toto` and `titi` by

```
>> b = strings{2}
b = 
toto

>> c = strings{3}
c = 
titi
```

Note that `strings{1}` is empty, since `a` starts with a newline character. Note also that you don't need a `strtrim` -- that is taken care of by `strread` already. You can circumvent the initial newlines by doing

```
strings = strread(a(2:end), '%s', 'delimiter', sprintf('\n'));
```

but I'd only do that if the first newline is consistently there for *all* cases. I'd much rather do

```
strings = strread(a, '%s', 'delimiter', sprintf('\n'));
strings = strings(~cellfun('isempty', strings))
```

Finally, if you'd rather use `textscan` instead of `strread`, you need to do 1 extra step:

```
strings = textscan(a, '%s', 'delimiter', sprintf('\n'));
strings = [strings{1}(2:end)];
```

Comment: this is what gives :                                                b =

toto                                                                     titi

Comment: whereas I need to get each value

Comment: Or, if that's not possible, could you post the output of `a+'0'` ?

Comment: I've updated the question by setting how I get the value of a

Comment: a+'0' gives :a+'0'

ans =

  Columns 1 through 14

    58    80    80    80    80    80    80    80    80    80    80    80    80   146

  Columns 15 through 28

   159   159   156   149   145   158   143   132    58    80    80    80    80    80

  Columns 29 through 42

    80    80    80    80    80    80    80   114   127   127   124    58    80    80

  Columns 43 through 49

    80    80    80    80    80    80    80

Comment: strings = textscan(a, '%s', 'delimiter', sprintf('\n')); gives : {3x1 cell}                                                          strings = [strings{2:end}]; gives : strings =

     []

Comment: Fixed it. I'm happy to have solved your problem, but for future reference -- please do not let us do your work. That last bug you could have easily fixed yourself.

Comment: strings = [strings{1}(2:end)];  gives : tototiti

Comment: I have 12a, what I need is to be able to get strings{1} and strings{2} , here it gives me : tototiti

Comment: Now why did you have to go and unaccept my answer? No need to act insulted; you just don't seem to be able to resolve even trivial coding problems, even after we've got you most of the way there. These are essential skills for any coder to have, and you should recognize that if you don't have them, it is simply wiser to switch to something else.

Comment: saying "then perhaps software development is not for you" is an insult , you did also tried several times to resolve my problem and not at first time, I find it wrong to say things like that, but thank you anyway!

Comment: Well, sorry then, it was not intended to be an insult, it was intended to be honest advice. It's merely a logical conclusion that anyone would draw from observing your questions and comments including, presumably, your employer.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `a` is a string with a newline in it. To make two separate variables, try:

```
values = strtrim(strread(a, '%s', 'delimiter', sprintf('\n')))
```

`strread` will split a into separate lines, and `strtrim` will remove leading/trailing whitespace.
Then you can access the lines using

```
values{1}
values{2}
```

(note that you must use curly brackets since this is a cell array of strings).

Comment: @Richante, is there another way to avoir use of strtrim ?

Comment: I looked at the documentation and see it's recommened to not use it as it will be removed , recommended textscan, but when I use it I don't have the disired behavior

Comment: @lola Can you back this up with a link or other evidence? No warnings on this in both R2012a and R2011b

Answer (score 1):

How are you reading in the xml file? If you're using xmlread then MatLab adds a lot of white space in there for you and could be the cause of your problems.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28518-xml2struct

This will put your xml file into a struct where you should be able to access the elements in the array.

Comment: Indeed, most likely the core of the problem