# Matlab : get value of variable

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [matlab get the value of char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952267/matlab-get-the-value-of-char)

from Matlab command , the value of y is :

```
y =


            toto
            titi
```

in variable workspace, the value is <1x49 char>
I need to get toto and titi
i've tried `y{1} and y{2}` but this isn't working , any Idea ?

thanks

Comment: read about matlab vector notation

Answer (score 1):

y{1} and y{2} only works if y is a cell array. If y is an array then you need to access it like y(1) and y(2). If you type whos('y'), it'll give you information on the variable in question.

Comment: y(1), and y(2) gives me empty field

Answer (score 1):

You have a character array, quite an inconvenient one too. 
You can convert this array in a more manageable form by doing

```
a = cellstr(a);
a = a(~cellfun(@isempty, a));
a = cellfun(@(x)strtrim(x),a,'uni',false);
```

Then you can reference to `toto` and `titi` by

```
>> b = a{1}
b = 
toto

>> c = a{2}
c = 
titi
```